# How Blazor Framework get notifed when the property value gets changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

When we have a HTML code like below.

```
<h1>@Title</h1>
```

and C# like below

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Think I have executed a code like below

```
Title = "New title updated in the runtime";
```

Then we see that the view has chenged with the new value.

How the renderer knows that the property value has changes.
Is there anything like `INotifyProperyChange` is implemented. How the HTML knows that this is the time to update the content.

I just want to know how the internals of the Blazor Framework are architectured.

Comment: @mjwills its a new open source framework still under experiment, currenly backed by Microsoft. it targets C# .Net (.net standard) to web assembly. https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor

Comment: I think there's an @bind tag now

Comment: @RichBryant ,  I just want to know how the internals of the Blazor Framework are architectured.

Comment: It would be useful externally as well, if for example you want the change of one value to trigger another function.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Blazor automatically checks for changes of bound properties when a user interaction happened (e.g. button click, text in an input changed). In that case, Blazor's JavaScript code triggers change detection in C# (=Webassembly). Therefore, you do not need to do anything if you want to refresh the UI after a user interaction.

However, there are cases in which you want to refresh the UI although no user interaction happened (e.g. timer). In that case, you have to call `StateHasChanged`. I have created a more detailed example on [learn-blazor.com](https://learn-blazor.com/pages/data-binding/).

Comment: But how does this change detection work? Does it check all properties for changes? Isn't that slow?